# How to extract resources from .msi files

Tags: c, windows, winapi, language-agnostic, windows-installer

How to extract resources (bitmaps,icons) from built .msi files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are resource kept in Binary table, from the MSI. You can open the MSI with Orca tool, go to this table, and double click the "Data" column, you will then be prompted with option to export the resource or even overwrite it.

Answer (score 4):

Try decompressing it with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver) (on OS X).

Comment: Decompressing the .MSI will just extract the files to be deployed. For files used by the installer itself (images, dlls of custion actions, see answer from BogdanMitrache).